# Use own FontForge font in XeLaTeX

Tags: fontspec, fontforge

I created a font for 12 letters, since this is all I need. Having created the font as .ttf I double click on it and press install. With \fontspec I want to see how the font looks like, but I get only the rectangle frame, meaning that the letters are not defined. But when I use LibreOffice I can use my newly installed self made font.
I guess I am making a stupid mistake somewhere, but could someone help me find it.

What I see using XeLaTeX.
[image]

What I see using LibreOffice Writer.
[image]

Comment: LaTeX is not able to use `ttf` font. You should use LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX instead.

Comment: can you provide the font for a test?

Comment: Rectangle normally means that xelatex did find the font but that there are no letters in the requested positions so it is quite either a problem with the font itself or xelatex found another one. Use \XeTeXtracingfonts=1 to find out which font is used and check the pdf properties.

Comment: font: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B5OYzdvI2MB5ejJya1BkbjVLLWs/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 1):

Your font works just fine. Here's a complete example. As you can see I specify the path where I downloaded your font as I have no intention of installing a font that only has five letters and big problems with spacing ... `:)`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Untitled1}[Path=L:/fonts/downloads/]
\begin{document}
BEACH
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: For me it still doesn't work. I work with Ubuntu 12.04, use Document Viewer 3.4.0 and Okular 0.14.3

Comment: @Hiro "Document Viewer" is Ubuntu's name for Evince, right? The pdf produced above looks fine in Evince here.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Which version of Evince are you using?

Comment: @Hiro I don't think the problem here is the version of Evince. My guess is that you're running an outdated version of `fontspec`. Please provide more details in your question (you can edit it) about your TeX distribution.

Comment: That must have been the reason. I have instell TEXLive anew and now it works.

Comment: @Sverre Apparently your above comment solved this old problem, due to user error (TeXlive too old). But the question was automatically bumped to the home page because the OP never accepted an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you have install the font on the path that XeLaTeX will search for any font you should be able to use the font:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec} %to be able to change the font
\setmainfont{Your font name here.ttf}

\begin{document}
The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
\end{document}
```

Your pdf viewer should also be able to use the font.

Edit: from fontspec package documentation:

> To load a font that is not in one of the default search paths, its
>   location in the filesystem must be specified with the Path feature:
>   \setmainfont{texgyrepagella}[ Path = /Users/will/Fonts/ , UprightFont
>   = *-regular , BoldFont = *-bold , ... ]

Comment: I have installed into the right location since I don't get any error messages when running XeLaTeX. And could it be a problem with the pdf viewer if I can see the font the LibreOffice?

Comment: @Hiro no warning too?

Comment: no warnings: [XeLaTeX] 0errors, 0 warnings, 0 badboxes

Comment: @Hiro : In this case I don't know sorry